# Google Container Registry build trigger on folder change

Tags: google-container-registry

I can setup a build trigger on GCR to build my Docker image every time my Git repository gets updated.  However, I have a single repository with multiple folders, and a Docker file in each folder.

Ex:

- my_app

  -- service-1

  ```
   Dockerfile-1
  ```

  -- service-2

  ```
  Dockerfile-2
  ```

How do I only build Dockerfile-1 when the service-1 folder gets updated?

Answer (score 3):

This is a variation on this [GitHub feature request](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloud-builders/issues/138) -- in your case, differential behavior based on the changed files (folders) rather than the branch.

We are considering this feature as part of the development of support for more advanced workflow control and will post back on that GitHub issue when it becomes available.

The work-around available to you today is to use a bash script that conditionally builds (or doesn't) based on an inspection of the files changed in the `$COMMIT_SHA` that triggered the build. Note that the [git builder](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloud-builders/tree/master/git) can be used to get the list of files changed via `git diff-tree --no-commit-id --name-only -r $COMMIT_SHA`.

Comment: any upate on this ? or we have to still go  with the suggested old approach ? if you can please help on this that would be really helpful.

Comment: i am also looking for same solution : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67261411/could-build-mono-repo-and-deploy-services-to-gke